# generate continuously midi sound with changing note number

Tags: midi

I am generating and playing continuously midi sound. During this generating and playing I am changing pitch wheel. This changing is working wothout problems. But I need change note number too. If i use message Note on playing is stopping and starting. Is it possible to change note number without stopping playing sound?

Comment: What's the difference between changing the pich and changing the note?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way of doing this this directly - if you get to the limit of the pitchbend range and you need to to beyond it the only way is to stop that note and start a new one.  One option could be to redefine the pitchbend range to be much larger so that you can reach more notes before you need to re-trigger a note on.  Another option is to use a sound with a longer attack and release so that the end of one note and the start of the next will cross-fade so that it'll sound continuous.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can I redefine pitchbend to larger range? Now I use range from $0000 to $ffff, is it possible to use larger range?

Comment: You need to use an RPN message (Registered Parameter Number - see [here](http://www.philrees.co.uk/nrpnq.htm)), though not all MIDI devices support it.

Comment: I can't redefine bend range, I try this code:                       midiOutMessage(hMidi, $cc100, 0, 0);
midiOutMessage(hMidi, $cc101, 0, 0);
midiOutMessage(hMidi, $dd6, 16, 0); But without success.